# Python code to return one column of a csv file wont return any data

Tags: python, csv

I am using python with emacs to retrieve one column from a csv table of combined data from GALEX and SDSS. When I run the code in my terminal, it doesn’t return any data and it doesn’t give an error message.

When I get the code to run I would like it to open and save the results in a new file. How do I get my code to print the desired data column and then save it in its own new file?

This is my code right now:
Members is the table, and Dec in the name of the column that I am selecting, which is at an index of 2 from the left of the header. I am returned an error message when I use an integer in the place of index in line four right now, which is the reason I have left it as the word.

```
#!usr/bin/python
def get_column(members,column_Dec):
    with open(members, 'r') as fid:
        header = fid.readline()
        column_2=header.split(',').index(column_Dec)
        column_data = []
        for line in fid:
            column_data.append(line.split(',')[column_2]) 
    return column_data
    print column_data
```

Sample of members data:

```
Group# RA       Dec       Redshift  a   b      c  d        e
 2293  215.197952   4.370193  0.02667  -18.116  0.739  0  0.950    1.71
 2293  215.186829   4.257247  0.02722  -18.379  0.660  0  0.950    1.59
```

Comment: First of all, you should definitely consider using the standard `csv` module for parsing CSV data. A naive `split(',')` won't work with valid CSV data like `john,smith,"Anchorage, AK"`, which should be interpreted as three columns, not four. Secondly, you need to `print` before you `return`. `return` stops execution of the function.

Comment: That can't be your code: `fid.realine()` has a typo.  Please always copy and paste your code exactly; otherwise people have to guess what your real code looks like.

Comment: @Chris The code above was a code suggested to me by someone else on stackoverflow. I switched the order of the return and print commands and got the same results. That being said, would  you recommend that I abandon this method all together and just use the standard model?

Comment: @DSM Sorry for having a typo. I corrected it. I was having issues copy and pasting from emacs on to the forum so I typed it out by hand. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: @Mart.Astro, well if you put `print` after `return` it definitely won't get called. Switching the order of those two doesn't guarantee that it will work, though. And yes, I do recommend using the `csv` module. It's included in the standard library, and it handles CSV parsing and writing quite well. How are you calling your function? Can you post a snippet from your members file?

Comment: @Chris I was calling it with the path of both the members file and then the column, however since the column doesn’t have a different path it didn't work. I think I'm going to try the CSV method. Would I just import the CSV module in my terminal with python? This is a snippet of my members file:

Comment: @Mart.Astro, the members file snippet should go in the question body, not in a comment. Use the "edit" link. It looks like you're using Python 2, so [this documentation for `csv.reader` should get you started](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#module-contents).

Comment: @Chris Okay good that is what I had been reading already, I posted the sample to the question, the formatting was alerted in the process.

Comment: `#!usr/bin/python`  should it be `#!/usr/bin/python` ?

Comment: @haifzhan i think it is correct the way it is as it have worked with previous codes, however I could be wrong